# Breeze.js Expand with select

Tags: javascript, many-to-many, breeze

There is no support to use expand with select in breeze.js:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from("TagConnections")
                  .expand("ttQuestions").where("QuestionID", "!=", null)
                  .select("ttQuestions"); // not possible
```

Is there a workaround?

Can i get/run queries/selections on the query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not a defect or limitation in Breeze. **The EntityFramework does not support the combination of select and expand**.  Breeze can ask the question for you but it is up to the server to deliver the goods. In this case, EF can't deliver the goods.

@zoidbergi - I don't fully see the "workaround" in your example. My guess is that you are performing the query without using the expand.  More importantly, you have revised the query to target the `Questions`, which is what you really wanted, rather than the `TagConnections`.

I suspect what you're missing ... and many of us want to have it too ... is the ability to express an "any" condition. If it were available, you could query for those `Questions` which are associated with any of the `TagConnections` that satisfy your filter criteria. You can write such a query in EF on the server. Unfortunately, you can't write that query in BreezeJS just yet.

Comment: yes. i wrote the any query on server. This is in acceptable solution for me now.

Comment: Breeze `any` and `all` query support was added in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround:

```
// client:
breeze.EntityQuery.from("Questions")
              .withParameters({ myParameter: "any addional query information" });

// server:
public IQueryable<ttQuestions> Questions(string myParameter=null)
{
    // handle parameters here
    ...
}
```